# Largest rectangle in curve

Tags: optimization, area, maxima-minima

There is a curve whose equation is given by $$y=9-x^2$$ Now find the area of largest rectangle that can be constructed in the curve. I proceeded like this$:$

I assumed the four points as $(x,y), (x,0), (-x,y), (-x,0)$ so the length of rectangle will become $2x$ and breadth will become $y$. So area$=2xy$. Or $2x(9-x^2)$ or $18x-2x^3$. Now for maximum area $\frac{dA}{dx}=0$ $\implies$ $$\frac{dA}{dx} 18x-2x^3 =0$$ $\implies$ $$18-6x^2=0$$ $\implies$ $$x=\sqrt{3}$$ Now I can simply find area. But I want to know can it be done without differentiation. As I have seen some sums like this which can be done by similarity or something like that. Just asking. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think this is a good question, but it's not [tag:differential-geometry]

Comment: Why do you assume that $(-x,0), (x,0)$ are vertices of the rectangle? Is it an explicit requirement of the problem? If so, you should update your question stating that.

Comment: So what is the tag, I will edit it?

Comment: I thought area would be largest when vertices lie on $x$ axis

Comment: You can graph $18x-2x^3$ and find maximum that way but it's like cheating :)

Comment: https://www.themathdoctors.org/max-and-min-of-a-cubic-without-calculus/

Comment: Can you simplify what the article$?$ I am having little difficulty to understand it.

Comment: To be a valid question, y must have a lower bound.  Like @mathcounterexamples.net said please clarify.

Comment: @Pmath *I thought area would be largest when vertices lie on $x$ axis*. This is not evident... at least for me! It deserves at least a good argument.